# Magento SOAP Login gives this error 'Premature end of data in tag html line 2'

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I'm working on an integration with a client website in to my app. for this I use SOAP.

This is the url: http://52.40.180.117/demo/uae_en/

Now the problems.

1) If I use standard SOAP URL as mentioned in Magento SOAP guide I do not get the xml output. Instead I get 404 error

http://52.40.180.117/demo/uae_en/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl - gives 404 error

http://52.40.180.117/demo/uae_en/api/v2_soap/?wsdl - Gives WSDL XML

Why is this? And how can I make it to work with standard URL as given in Magento website.

2) If I use SOAP UI application to test SOAP functions, I get all the function listings. But when I send a request using login function I get following error,

```
‘SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
'http://52.40.180.117/demo/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Premature 
 end of data in tag html line 2’
```

Can anyone give any suggestions to fix this issue and make this work please?

[image: request for login and token]

[image: response from Magento]

Comment: Can anyone give any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: It seems because of the page redirect (to ../uae_en/..) Magento could not read its own WSDL internally.  It seems its a bug I guess. Anyone has got any suggestions?